# How can I transform values inside a function onClick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, webgl

Basically, I've imported a WebGL globe and want to make it stop spinning when I click on the globe.

Here's my attempt at making it stop:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        var c = earth.getPosition();
        earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.9]);
        earth.onclick.setCenter({c[0], c[1]);
    }, 50);
```

Basically I want to get rid of the `+0.9` onClick. If it helps, also adding the function with the earth object below:

```
<script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var options = {atmosphere: true, center: [0, 0], zoom: 0};
    var earth = new WE.map('earth_div', options);
    WE.tileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
        subdomains: '1234',
        attribution: 'Tiles Courtesy of MapQuest'
    }).addTo(earth);
</script>
```

I'm guessing my syntax isn't correct with the `.onclick`. What should it be instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the examples on [webglearth](http://examples.webglearth.org/#apidemo), the `onClick` is defined as:

```
earth.on('click', callback)
```

So you need to define the callback function as:

```
callback = function(){···}
```

or in short:

```
earth.on('click', function(e){···});
```

If you need to stop the animation, you have to use `clearInterval` on `onClick` event

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var c = earth.getPosition();
    earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.9]);
}, 50);
···
earth.on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: U r welcome!! yep, especially if you come from languages like python or ruby

Answer (score -1):

According to http://www.webglearth.org/api, it should be `earth.on('click', yourCallback());`, not .onclick. Also, I would consider some changes to your code:

First off, don't set the onclick handler within the setatimeout function all the time. Do it one time on intialization and use a variable instead of 0.9 inside the timeout that u can set to 0 inside your onclick callback. In case you want to stop animation forever, you might consider breaking out of the setTimeout loop in case you stumble upon that variable being 0.

Im gonna leave implementation up to you

Comment: Apologies in advance, still picking up JS. I 1) added `var stopSpeed = rotationspeed.replace("0.1", "0.0");` under the `initialize()` function, 2) added a separate function to call that variable `function stopEarth() {earth.on('click', stopSpeed());}`, and 3) set the speed to a variable, i.e. `var rotationspeed = 0.1;

          earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + rotationspeed]);`. Would that work?